# Possible to read keyboard shortcuts table in macOS?

Tags: bash, cocoa, keyboard-shortcuts, macos-catalina, macos-carbon

Is it possible to access the keyboard shortcuts file/table in macOS (Catalina 10.15.4) from a shell script or an API?

I'm considering writing a routine to lookup existing shortcuts to help prevent their overwrite
while assigning a custom one.

There are far too many of them for a manual lookup, with or without third-party tools.

I was considering something like Visual Studios's implementation in Keyboard Options:

[image: keyboard options]